# CSS Print. Not breaking into pages

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

I wrote CSS to format for printing, and I have been able to get it to do everything I need except for breaking into pages. When I do a print the preview just shows a chunk of the page with a scroll bar on the side, but won't break it into pages. I tried adding the following to my **@media print {}** :

```
div, body, ol, ul, p {
    overflow: visible;
}
p {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

None of this, however, has fixed my problem. What am I missing?

Also, I don't know if it matters but I am using Angular 1.5.11

Comment: Try `page-break-before`

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb  Tried it, no change.

Comment: Maybe try both?

Comment: Still no difference